# barcode in PDF to Code39 conversion in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a PDF file which contains just 1 Page. I have a barcode at the end of the page. 
How do I extract the barcode number from the PDF in C#

I have seen a post to convert barcode Image to Code 39 but how do we do it from PDF, Please help
[barcode image to Code39 conversion in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204008/barcode-image-to-code39-conversion-in-c#204084)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to get a PDF library that can extract images from the pages. We use Aspose.PDF and Aspose.PDF.Kit, which are both excellent products.

http://www.aspose.com

This page shows a code example of how to extract an image from a PDF document:

http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/extract-image-from-pdf-document.html

They also have a Barcode library, and one of the things it can do is read barcodes from multi-page tiff images. You could convert the pages of your PDF to TIFF and then use the barcode library to read the barcodes:

http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/how-to-read-barcode-from-multipage-tiff-images.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) library to convert the PDF to an image and then a barcode reading library such as [IBScanner](http://www.ibscanner.com) to extract the barcode(s) from the image.